# Change value of stripe charge with a select field before submit (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a form to sign up for appointments.  However, each appointment has a different price (db: appointment belongs to appt_type, price belongs to appt_type). Here's how my collection_select is set up:

```
# @appointments = Appointment.all
# form_for ...
<div>
  <%= f.label "Select Date" %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:appointment_id, @appointments, :id, :formated_date, :class => 'select_class')%>
</div>
```

Here's how my stripe form is set up:

```
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
    data-description= Description
    data-amount= ?????
  </script>
<% end %>
```

I'd like the change the value of data-amount to reflect the price of the selected appointment in the collection_select. It seems that this has to be done dynamically but I'm not sure how to go about it.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically change the price of Checkout when using this form. Instead, you need to use [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) to set the price in Javascript. The idea here is that you have your own button to open Checkout in your form first. Then, in the click handler, you call `handler.open()` with the parameters you want, including the price you've calculated based on the customer's choice in the dropdown.

You can see a working demo of this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ra010dby/1/) but here's what your code would look like:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh',
    image: '/square-image.png',
    token: function(token) {
        $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
        $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }
  });

  $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
    var amount = $("#amount").val() * 100;
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets ($20.00)',
      amount: amount
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
```